# Order creation with no invoice

Tags: orders, invoice, create-invoice

Using Magento 1.8.1.0

Occasionally an order is produced (which has successfully been paid for) but the corresponding invoice is not produced.

This has happened a few times, but only occasionally.  We cannot understand why.  Can anyone shed any light on it, and how to stop it happening?

Comment: What is the payment method? Are you sure, the invoice should be created automatically?

Comment: Yes, we gets lots of orders where the invoice is created automatically, this is why its a puzzle when some are not.

Comment: The payment method is SagePay

Comment: What is the order status for the ones that are invoice and the ones that are not?

Comment: I'm pretty sure (not 100%) that both the orders which invoice automatically and those which do not are both set to 'processing'.  When we notice an invoice is missing, we will check payment has been received, and manually create the invoice.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with another payment module that redirects the customer to a separate payment page. 
The order was created in redirectAction however invoice was issued in successAction. 
Which means that if the customer gets to the payment page and pays it successfully but closes the browser before redirecting back to your site, the order is created but the invoice is not issued. I don't know if that's the case for you but I hope it helps someone